# Laravel 5: Model object could call Builder method. How does Laravel do that?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

In the Laravel package, the model User is derived from Model class.
Although Model class does not have "join" method, I could still use join method on the user object.

I am not clear how does Laravel do that.

```
$user = Users::find($id);
$user->
    join('GroupMember', 'GroupMember.UserID', '=', 'users.id')->
    join('Groups', 'GroupMember.GroupID', '=', 'Groups.GroupID')->
    where('users.id','=', $user->id)->get();
```

The above code is to get all related groups of the user. 
Because the $user is derived from Model class, but the Model class dos not have "join" method...

Here is the User definition.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Eloquent uses `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` behind the scenes and you can find all those methods in this `Builder` class.

When you run function that does not exist in `Users` model in this case, [magic method `__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) is used:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
    }

    $query = $this->newQuery();

    return call_user_func_array([$query, $method], $parameters);
}
```

as you see in this method `newQuery` method is executed. And when you look at this method definitions you can see here:

```
public function newQuery()
{
    $builder = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();

    foreach ($this->getGlobalScopes() as $identifier => $scope) {
        $builder->withGlobalScope($identifier, $scope);
    }

    return $builder;
}
```

and further, when you look at `newQueryWithoutScopes` you'll see there:

```
$builder = $this->newEloquentBuilder(
        $this->newBaseQueryBuilder()
);
```

and this `newEloquentBuilder` method returns `new Builder($query);` so it's an `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`$user = Users::find($id);` returns eloquent User model or null. So you can't use a 'join' on it as it is not a builder object.

`$user = Users::whereId($id);` will return a query builder, hence you can use a 'join' on that.

Alternatively, you can write it like so -

```
$user = Users::find($id);
$user->with([
'GroupMember' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('GroupMember.UserID', '=', 'users.id')
},
'Groups' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('GroupMember.GroupID', '=', 'Groups.GroupID')
}]),
->where('users.id','=', $user->id)
->get();
```